# Not displaying data on PHP file

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to learn some new stuff and always wanted to learn how to make a website with PHP and mysql...

I found this easy tutorial and sample files to play with

http://css-tricks.com/php-for-beginners-building-your-first-simple-cms/

I'm trying to add another table it works in the database but when I try to display it it don't work. Here is the code I got and using:

```
<?php

class simpleCMS {

  var $host;
  var $username;
  var $password;
  var $table;

  public function display_public() {
    $q = "SELECT * FROM laptopvoltage ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 3";
    $r = mysql_query($q);

    if ( $r !== false && mysql_num_rows($r) > 0 ) {
      while ( $a = mysql_fetch_assoc($r) ) {
        $lvmodel = stripslashes($a['lvmodel']);
        $lvmanuf = stripslashes($a['lvmanuf']);
        $lvvolt = stripslashes($a['lvvolt']);

        $entry_display .= <<<ENTRY_DISPLAY

    <div class="post">
        <h2>
            $lvmodel
        </h2>
        <p> !!!!!!this dont show upp!!!!!! - - - - >>>>>
          $lvmanuf
        </p><----------- WHY?
        <p>
          $lvvolt
        </p>
    </div>

ENTRY_DISPLAY;
      }
    } else {
      $entry_display = <<<ENTRY_DISPLAY

    <h2> This Page Is Under Construction </h2>
    <p>
      No entries have been made on this page. 
      Please check back soon, or click the
      link below to add an entry!
    </p>

ENTRY_DISPLAY;
    }
    $entry_display .= <<<ADMIN_OPTION

    <p class="admin_link">
      <a href="{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?admin=1">Add a New Entry</a>
    </p>

ADMIN_OPTION;

    return $entry_display;
  }

  public function display_admin() {
    return <<<ADMIN_FORM

    <form action="{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}" method="post">

      <label for="lvmodel">Title:lv model</label><br />
      <input name="lvmodel" id="lvmodel" type="text" maxlength="150" />
      <div class="clear"></div>

      <label for="lvmanuf">Title:lv manu</label><br />
      <input name="lvmanuf" id="lvmanuf" type="text" maxlength="150" />
      <div class="clear"></div>
      <label for="lvvolt">Title:lvvolt</label><br />
      <input name="lvvolt" id="lvvolt" type="text" maxlength="150" />
      <div class="clear"></div>

      <input type="submit" value="Create This Entry!" />
    </form>

    <br />

    <a href="display.php">Back to Home</a>

ADMIN_FORM;
  }

  public function write($p) {
    if ( $_POST['lvmodel'] )
      $lvmodel = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lvmodel']);
    if ( $_POST['lvmanuf'] )
      $lvmanuf = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lvvolt']);
       if ( $_POST['lvvolt'] )
      $lvvolt = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lvvolt']);
    if ( $lvmodel && $lvmanuf && $lvvolt ) {
      $created = time();
      $sql = "INSERT INTO laptopvoltage VALUES('$lvmodel','$lvmanuf','$lvvolt','$created')";
      return mysql_query($sql);
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  public function connect() {
    mysql_connect($this->host,$this->username,$this->password) or die("Could not connect. " . mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db($this->table) or die("Could not select database. " . mysql_error());

    return $this->buildDB();
  }

  private function buildDB() {
    $sql = <<<MySQL_QUERY
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS laptopvoltage (
lvmodel     VARCHAR(150),
lvmanuf TEXT,
lvvolt  VARCHAR(150),
created     VARCHAR(100)
)
MySQL_QUERY;

    return mysql_query($sql);
  }

}

?>
```

it just wont show `$lvmanuf`. Any help on this would be great as the fields are showing up in my database.

Comment: Learning PHP from a site called CSS-Tricks.. Yeah.. I'd suggest you leave that site and forget everything you learned there. mysql_*-methods are deprecated and should not be used.

Comment: You can start here -> 
http://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info

Comment: this is for a desktop project f mine so it would only be ran in a lamp software can you see where the problem is?

Comment: @AmalMurali and there goes that copypasta again. Sigh.

Comment: thanks for the replies :) can someone point me to a file like the one i posted in the question. i am extremly basic and seeing and playig with the code is the best way for me to learn

Comment: @RickNash Are you sure that field has been populated with data on your database?

Comment: Btw the article you're using is **4 years old**. You'd better try to find something up-to-date, this is centuries in the computer world.

Comment: @RickNash Are you also sure that the fieldname on the database table is `lvmanuf`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this first file only shows results, if your not to familiar with web logic and design then ill try my best to explain, this first file is called index.php, every website and web-application has a file either call index.html or index.php the reason behind this is that the web server looks for a file named either index.html or index.php and dont misunderstand there are more than just these file types and names a server can start off of its just that these are the most common, since that is out of the way now i will explain the code behind the first file.

as you can see we have set up our basic html document inside and added a script, now the script we made will make the files that are loaded inside the id we specified disappear after a set ammount of seconds, next inside the body of the html we put this code,

```
<span id="messages">

<?php include "constant.php"; ?>    

</span>
```

this code contains to main players for this script first the span tag with the id attribute tells our javascript the id of the text we want to be invisible after the set amount of seconds, next the

```
<php include "constant.hpp"; ?>
```

it includes every thing from the constant.php document we make.

file 1

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /><meta http-equiv="content-language" content="en-US" />
    <title>MySQL Connection test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function()
        {
            timedHide(document.getElementById('messages'), 10);
        }

        function timedHide(element, seconds)
        {
            if (element) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                element.style.display = 'none';
             }, seconds*1000);
         }
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <span id="messages">

    <?php include "constant.php"; ?>

    </span>
</body>
</html>
```

this second file im not going to explain to much about it, since it would make this way to long, but this file is the connection file to the mysql database.

the only part you need to fill in on this is the

$database_ip = ""; //database ip adress goes inside quotes

$database_port = ""; //database port goes inside quotes

$database_name = ""; //database name goes inside quotes

$database_admin_user = ""; //admin username goes inside quotes

$database_admin_pass = ""; //admin password goes inside quotes

this will connect your website to the database.

file 2

constant.php

```
<?php
$database_ip = ""; //database ip adress goes inside quotes
$database_port = ""; //database port goes inside quotes
$database_name = ""; //database name goes inside quotes

$database_admin_user = ""; //admin username goes inside quotes
$database_admin_pass = ""; //admin password goes inside quotes

//do not modify anything past this point unless you know php well.

$database_link = null;

$database_defaults = array("127.0.0.1","3306","MySQL","root","");
$error_defaults = array("error_no_101" => "required field *IP is empty, using default parameters!",
                        "error_no_102" => "required field *PORT is empty, using default parameters!",
                        "error_no_103" => "required field *NAME is empty, using default parameters!",
                        "error_no_104" => "required field *USER is empty, using default parameters!",
                        "error_no_105" => "required field *PASS is empty, using default parameters!");

if(empty($database_ip)){
    $database_ip = $database_defaults[0];
    echo $error_defaults["error_no_101"] . "<br/>";
}

if(empty($database_port)){
    $database_port = $database_defaults[1];
    echo $error_defaults["error_no_102"] . "<br/>";
}

if(empty($database_name)){
    $database_name = $database_defaults[2];
    echo $error_defaults["error_no_103"] . "<br/>";
}

if(empty($database_admin_user)){
    $database_admin_user = $database_defaults[3];
    echo $error_defaults["error_no_104"] . "<br/>";
}

if(empty($database_admin_pass)){
    $database_admin_pass = $database_defaults[4];
    echo $error_defaults["error_no_105"] . "<br/>";
}

$database_link = mysqli_connect($database_ip, $database_admin_user, $database_admin_pass, $database_name);

if (!$database_link) {
    die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') ' . mysqli_connect_error());
} else {
    echo 'Success... ' . mysqli_get_host_info($database_link) . "\n";
}

mysqli_close($database_link);

?>
```

i put this up to help you fix your code, not to teach you the syntax of the language.

to learn the syntax of php i recommend you go here:

this is the official php website documentation that teach you the correct way to code php,

http://www.php.net/manual/en/langref.php

you could also try this place if you have the money for a subscription:

http://www.lynda.com/MySQL-tutorials/PHP-MySQL-Essential-Training/119003-2.html?srchtrk=index:1%0Alinktypeid:2%0Aq:php%0Apage:1%0As:relevance%0Asa:true%0Aproducttypeid:2

for html you could go to:

http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp

you could also try this place if you have the money for a subscription:

http://www.lynda.com/HTML-tutorials/HTML-Essential-Training-2012/99326-2.html

Comment: How does this answer his question?

Comment: i put this out there for him to use because, the code he found was very sloppy, and contained bad practice. he also stated that he was having problems with the code not responding with his database. so i thus answered his question for the broken code, by putting out some code that i know works

Comment: `alert('Hello world !');` : I know this code works, that doesn't mean it answers the question.

Comment: While this is an attempt at answering this question it in fact is not a very good answer (yet) - please consider explaining how you think this solves OP's question.